# View/extract file signature information in linux

Tags: linux, authentication

I'm trying to view  file signature information of a file on linux. I have spent all day to search on google but no help.
On Windows, when right click on a file and choose Property. if that file was signed, there will show a tab "Digital Signatures" which show signature information such as signer, expired date ...

Does anyone know how to show these information on linux(ubuntu) ?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score -1):

what kind of file are you try to see the signature of ?

Try to look at this page if its an exe: http://hype-free.blogspot.dk/2008/09/how-to-verify-executable-digital.html